# Append divs from array using jQuery show Animation

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have some divs in an array. I want to use the .show('slow') Animation from jQuery.

Currently i have this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < output.length; i++){
    jQuery("#container").append(output[i]).show('slow');
}
```

But all divs get appended instantly. I think the problem is that every append does not wait for the next append?

Are you guys having an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the code operations shown happen on the same frame. Just hide them first.

Assuming the array is strings of `div`s:

```
for (var i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
    jQuery("#container").append($(output[i]).hide().delay(2000* i).show('slow'));
}
```

The second issue is that you want to chain the visual fades, one after the other, in which case simply introduce an increasing delay before the `show`s. Just adjust the timing value to get the effect you want.

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/nvffL4zt/1/

Answer (score 1):

First **hide** the divs, then **append** them, and then **show** them. The trick lies in using appendTo(), because normal append() returns the container, not the appended element. So you're using show() on the container, not the appended div.

```
for (var i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {

    jQuery(output[i])).hide().appendTo("#container").show('slow');   
}
```

Comment: The closure you added from @Bala's answer is not required.

Answer (score 0):

You have two solution, either you put an inline style on your divs with display:none; either you affect them a class (let's say "hidden"), and you put
.hidden{display:none} in your css.

The problem is that your divs are displayed when you append them, and the show function is useless because your divs are already visible.

Answer (score 0):

use **closure**

```
for (var i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
    (function (i) {
        jQuery("#container").append(output[i]).children().last().hide().show('slow');
    })(i);

}
```

Comment: This closure will make no difference as the commands start immediately